# Archivo .js deja de trabajar al incluir una función nueva

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un archivo .js en donde voy codificando todas las funciones que traten con validaciones de formulario, es decir, evitar que el usuario duministre información basura al sistema. El caso es que, hasta el momento, tengo dos funciones que cumplen muy bien su trabajo, sin embargo, al momento en que agrego una tercera función, parece como si el sistema dejase de reconocer el .js, los formularios se envian sin antes validar.

este es el .js con las dos funciones que evidentemente sirve.

```
function validar(){

var nombre, cedula, checkin, checkout, telefono, huespedes, habitacion;

nombre = document.getElementById('nom').value;
cedula = document.getElementById('cedu').value;
checkin = document.getElementById('in').value;
checkout = document.getElementById('out').value;
telefono = document.getElementById('tel').value;
huespedes = document.getElementById('hues').value;
habitacion = document.getElementById('cmb').value;

filter = /^[A-Za-z\_\-\.\s\xF1\xD1]+$/;

    if(nombre ==="" || cedula ==="" || telefono==="" || huespedes==="" || habitacion==="0"){
            alert("Por favor verifique los campos del formulario");
            return false;
    }

    else if(telefono.length>11 || telefono<0){
        alert("Ingrese un numero telefonico correcto");
        return false;
    } 

    else if(isNaN(telefono)){
        alert("Ingrese un numero telefonico correcto");
        return false;
    }

    else if(huespedes.length>2 || huespedes<1){
        alert("Ingrese una cantidad acorde");
        return false;
    } 

    else if(isNaN(huespedes)){
        alert("Ingrese la cantidad en digitos");
        return false;
    }

    else if(cedula.length>8){
        alert("Ingrese un numero de cedula correcto");
        return false;
    }

    else if(cedula < 0){
        alert("Ingrese un numero de cedula correcto");
        return false;
    }

    else if(isNaN(cedula)){
        alert("Ingrese un numero de cedula correcto");
        return false;
    }

    else if(nombre.length<5 || nombre.length>20){
        alert("Ingrese una razon social valida");
        return false;
    }

    else if(!filter.test(nombre)){
        alert("Ingrese correctamente una razÃ³n social");
        return false;
    }

    if(huespedes > 3 && habitacion ==="Matrimonial"){
        alert("La cantidad de huespedes no coincide con la capacidad de la habitacÃ­Ã³n");
        return false;
    }

    //Preguntar al profesor como validar los campos Date para que el usuario no elija fechas pasadas, tambien como colocarle un nombre tipo placeholder 
}

function validacion(){

    var nombre, correo, comentario, filtro, expresion;

    filtro = /\w+@+\w+\.+[a-z]/;
    expresion = /^[A-Za-z\_\-\.\s\xF1\xD1]+$/;

    nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    correo = document.getElementById('correo').value;
    comentario = document.getElementById('comentario').value;

    if(nombre ==="" || correo ==="" || comentario===""){
        alert("Por favor rellene los campos solicitados");
        return false;
    }

    if(nombre.length > 50){
        alert("El nombre es muy largo");
        return false;
    }

    if(!expresion.test(nombre)){
        alert("Ingrese un nombre válido");
        return false;
    }

    if(!filtro.test(correo)){
        alert("Ingrese una direccion de correo válida");
        return false;
    }

}
```

A continuación el codigo que al agregar al archivo .js hace que todo deje de funcionar

```
function validar_login(){

    var usuario, contraseña;

    usuario = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    contraseña = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    if(usuario==="" || contraseña ===""){
        alert("rellene los campos");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cabe destacar lo siguiente. Estoy capturando los datos desde un archivo html mediante la función onsubmit, obviamente enlazo este archivo al .js a través del header (son cosas que quizá son lógicas pero es importante mencionarlas para que puedan responderme correctamente). Entonces, ¿Qué puede estar ocasionando este tipo de error? Saludos.

**Editado:**

Agrego el código html de uno de los formularios del sistema,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>POSADA SANTIAGO C.A</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="validar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="contenedor">

    <header>
        <h2>POSADA SANTIAGO C.A</h2>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="index.php">Inicio</a>
        <a href="reservar.php">Reservar</a>
        <a href="contacto.php">Contactanos</a>
        <a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>

        <label >
        <form action="login.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validar_login()">
            <i title="Iniciar Sesión" class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Admin">
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Pass">
            <button type="submit"><i title="Login" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </form>
        </label>

    </nav>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código HTML para poder ver cómo se está mandando llamar las funciones y los elementos HTML a los que haces referencia desde tu JS por favor?

Comment: ¿Con "Todo deje de funcionar" te refieres a que no valida ningún campo? Usando el HTML de tu forma y la función `validar_login()` funciona correctamente, si no llenas ambos campos no te deja subir el formulario, podrías ser un poco más detallado sobre el comportamiento del formulario cuando agregas esa función a tu JS?

Comment: Tengo otros dos formularios en mi sistema, los cuales funcionan bien, validan si agrego datos y si no los agrego obviamente no envia nada, lo notifica. Cuando agrego la función _validar_login()_ al archivo js que contiene las demás funciones que validan a esos formularios que ya funcionaban correctamente, estos dejan de validar. Envían la información basura o los campos vacios a la bd. Espero ser específico.

Comment: Entonces haría falta agregues otro formulario donde se pueda reproducir el problema para poder dar una solución, ya que como está el código en estos momentos funciona correctamente para validar los campos de nombre y contraseña

Comment: Qué error te sale en el la consola del navegador?, haz probado no usar la "ñ" para tu variable contraseña?